# Average values in all dicts with matching values for a given key in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionnaries that all have the same keys.

```
in_list = [{'index':1, 'value':2.}, {'index':1, 'value':3.}, {'index':2, 'value':4.}]
```

I'd like to create a new dictionnary with the average on `'value'` for each `'index'`.

```
out_dict = {1:2.5, 2:4.}
```

What would be the most pythonic way to do this ?

---

The following code does what I want, but I feel like it is clumsy

```
tmp = {x:[] for x in range(1,3)}
for el in in_list:
    tmp[el['index']].append(el['value'])

for key, val in tmp.iteritems():
    out_dict[key] = sum(val)/len(val)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, but you can make it a little more compact. As Transhuman's answer shows you can avoid initialising `tmp` by making it a `defaultdict` of lists. Another way to do that is to use the [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method. And then use a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) to calculate the averages.

```
in_list = [
    {'index':1, 'value':2.}, 
    {'index':1, 'value':3.}, 
    {'index':2, 'value':4.}
]

out_dict = {}
for d in in_list:
    out_dict.setdefault(d['index'], []).append(d['value'])
out_dict = {k: sum(v) / len(v) for k, v in out_dict.items()}
print(out_dict)
```

**output**

```
{1: 2.5, 2: 4.0}
```

Answer (score 2):

To do it without any packages to install (long one-liner :-) ):

```
import itertools,statistics
a = dict(zip(sorted(set([i['index'] for i in lod])),[statistics.mean(int(item['value']) for item in group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(lod, key=lambda x: x['index'])]))
```

Now:

```
print(a)
```

Returns:

```
{1: 2.5, 2: 4}
```

If python 2:

```
import itertools
a = dict(zip(sorted(set([i['index'] for i in lod]),key=[i['index'] for i in lod].index),[sum(int(item['value']) for item in group)/len(int(item['value']) for item in group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(lod, key=lambda x: x['index'])]))
```

**Explanation:**

- get the ordered list of unique elements using `set`
- use `itertools.groupby` for grouping then iterate by `key` a `group`, the get average using `statistics` or `sum` and `len`
- the above two notes are all in a `zip`(`dict(zip(...))`)

Or to make the code little cleaner:

Python 3:

```
import itertools,statistics
unique_elements=sorted(set([i['index'] for i in lod]))
groups=statistics.mean(int(item['value']) for item in group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(lod, key=lambda x: x['index'])]
a = dict(zip(unique_elements,groups))
```

Python 2:

```
import itertools
unique=sorted(set([i['index'] for i in lod])
groups=[sum(int(item['value']) for item in group)/len(int(item['value']) for item in group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(lod, key=lambda x: x['index'])]
a = dict(unique,groups))
```

Comment: Ok, it works, but would you like to encounter this oneliner when having to read code?

Comment: @timgeb Yeah, doing a whole explanation

Comment: That's fine. I would use three lines of self-documenting code `unique_elements = ...`, `groups = ...`, `result = ...`. Instead of one line of code with three lines of explanation. ;)

Comment: @timgeb Hmm... i don't fully understand?

Comment: @timgeb Oh that's right, i was about to do that too

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your code is clumsy, but you could check out `pandas`.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> in_list = [{'index':1, 'value':2.}, {'index':1, 'value':3.}, {'index':2, 'value':4.}]
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(in_list)
>>> df.groupby(by='index').mean()
       value
index       
1        2.5
2        4.0
```

You can transform the result to a standard dictionary if you like.

```
>>> df.groupby(by='index').mean().to_dict()['value']
{1: 2.5, 2: 4.0}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do is using `collections.defaultdict`

```
in_list = [{'index':1, 'value':2.}, {'index':1, 'value':3.}, {'index':2, 'value':4.}]

from collections import defaultdict
d_dict = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in [d.values() for d in in_list]:
    d_dict[k].append(v)

{k:sum(v)/len(v) for k,v in d_dict.items()}
#{1: 2.5, 2: 4.0}
```